# Is Xubuntu supported as is Ubuntu

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are attempting to build a robot like PR2 (of [www.Willowgarage.com](http://www.Willowgarage.com)). We will need ROS.
We understand that before we can get ROS we need Ubuntu (to get the support from ROS);
However, my friend in the Riverside Robotic Society is talking about using Xubuntu. I understand that ROS.org supports Ubuntu but not sure if Xubuntu is the same.

If he uses Xubuntu is that the same as Ubuntu as far as loading ROS onto Xubuntu?

If Xubuntu is not supported, how can I get Ubuntu onto may HP Media Center PC m7357c that is running Microsoft XP?

Robert.N.Smith@ieee.org

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34912/is-xubuntu-supported-as-is-ubuntu/) by [RobertNealSmigth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2340/robertnealsmigth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-05-26

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I'm writing this lines from Xubuntu 11.10 with both installed Electric and Fuerte. I don't see any problems with them.:)

---

Originally posted by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) with karma: 546 on 2012-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-26**:
I believe any Ubuntu variant will work (Kubuntu, Xubuntu, etc.). Depending on what ROS packages you install, you might drag in substantial additional Ubuntu package dependencies.

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2012-05-26**:
I completely agree. There is no crucial difference between Ubuntu distros, except desktop environment and preinstalled soft.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-05-26**:
@CaptainTrunky Well, Xubuntu is lighter and needs lesser resources (Xfce based) - so that will be a visible advantage

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2012-05-27**:
I mean that there are no difference as, e.g., between Ubuntu and Gentoo. Ubuntu variants different in DE and preinstalled soft with all related things (such a requirements and needed resources). But I agree with you in this point.